# Can SSL Cert be shared across web site and virtual directory on IIS (asp.net)?

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

If I have a web site (mydomain.com) that has an ssl cert installed.  I then create a virtual directory mydomain.com/forums for example, and I want that site also to be covered by the same ssl cert.  Will that happen automatically with iis7 and on?  Is there something special I need to do do make that happen?  Any issues I need to be concerned about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity described in a certificate follows the rules defined in [RFC 2818 (Section 3.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1). This applies to the entire host, so the same certificate on `mydomain.com` will be valid for all the URIs within that host.

Note that I'm talking of URIs that use this host, not necessarily hosts on subdomains, e.g. `subdomain.mydomain.com`: in this case the certificate would have to be valid for that sub-domain too.

As I was saying in [this answer on Security.SE recently](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14021/2435), even with the more recent RFC 6125, which allows for URI entries in the certificate Subject Alternative Name (RFC 2818 only talks about DNS names or IP addresses), the validation doesn't go further than the host name.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. that makes sense to me.